# Fit a kernel density function

Tags: python, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing

I'm working on fitting a kernel density estimator and setting the correct bandwidth. The most popular technique is to minimise the following function. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)
$$
{\displaystyle \operatorname {MISE} (h)=\operatorname {E} \!\left[\,\int ({\hat {f}}_{h}(x)-f(x))^{2}\,dx\right].}  
$$

1. How can compute that in python? ${\hat {f}}_{h}(x)$ is pretty easy. But what about $f(x)$? There are no $y$ in KDEs.
2. Also is this equation equavalent to $\operatorname {E} \!\left[\,\int ({\hat {F}}_{h}(x)-F(x))^{2}\,dx\right]$ ?

Comment: What is the intended relationship between "$F$" and "$f$"?

Comment: F is the integral of f

Comment: $f$ is the true, underlying density, which is the very thing you're trying to estimate. Since it's unknown, you can't simply "compute that in python"